# RAM is being drained (around 6-7 GB) with no process trace

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, playstation

Im using a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit PC system with Intel i7 and 8 GB of RAM.
In random events like when using my PS3 or trying to watch movies the RAM usage rises to around 7 GB from only 1.5 GB before. Im trying to find what process that is draining all of my RAM. I have tried to look in task manager and MS Process explorer but with no trace of any high memmory usage at all (100 MB at maximum).

Could it be my ps3 or Divx player that im using to watch my movies?

(PS3 is using my Pc as mediaserver so i watch movies on my PS3 from my PC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sysinternals has a tool call [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) which will show you exactly how every page of your memory is allocated. Load it up and see where all that memory has gone. (And of course, post back and tell us what was happening!)

Comment: Thank you @Darth Android !
It was looking like all of my "Drained" RAM was being kept on "Standby-mode" by the system for the movies i was trying to watch.
I also noticed that when trying to watch movies on the PS3 the RAM was never freed. Even after shutting-off the PS3. But it did take around an hour for the ram to return to natrual state from 7 GB til 1.5 GB. I think the computer was still trying to send the movie over  even after it had been canceled. The feature of freeing my cached RAM was Really Helpful. Now its only for me to figure out why the system didnt let go of my cached RAM.